# Angle to a point on a chord

Tags: geometry, circles

Calculate angle $\alpha$ in the figure given the circle's radius $R$ and the distances $d=\overline{CM}$ and $\overline{CD}$.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9zvI.jpg)

Comment: use the sine rule

Comment: From the isoceles right triangle we know:  $\overline{CD} = \sqrt{2}R$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Established the equation below with the sine sule applied to $\triangle ACM$,

$$\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin (45+\alpha)}=\frac dR\implies
\tan\alpha =\frac d{\sqrt2 R-d}$$

which yields $\alpha = \tan^{-1}\frac d{\sqrt2 R-d}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

$ACD$ is an isosceles right triangle.

Consider triangle $CMA$ to apply Sine Rule:

$$ \dfrac{CM=d}{R}=\dfrac{\sin \alpha}{\sin (\pi/4+\alpha)}=\dfrac{\sqrt 2 \sin \alpha}{\sin \alpha + \cos \alpha};$$
$$\tan\alpha =\dfrac d{\sqrt2 R-d};$$